# GA enhanced e-commerce transnational data would not show for my Shopify store?

Tags: google-analytics, shopify, enhanced-ecommerce

I have a store running on Shopify [www.kabukithemes.com](http://www.kabukithemes.com/). I have followed the procedure here:

https://docs.shopify.com/manual/settings/general/google-analytics#enhanced-ecommerce

and enabled the Google enhanced analytics. All data is flowing to my GA account but not transactions. I can see visits, products views, products added to cart or abandoned. But there are no transactions.

I am using 2checkout as the payment gateway and all orders so far have been placed via 2checkout. I have my store, shopify and 2checkout.com in the Referral exclusion list of my GA profile for www.kabukithemes.com but still no transactions are being picked by my GA.

Has anyone had this problem and do you have any suggestions on how to solve it? It is hard to debug it because Shopify wrap the analytics script in their own script. At the same time it is totally impossible to get to their technical support. Their forum spam filters, block me every time I try to ask a question there. So please do not forward me to the Shopify forum to ask the question there.